# Play wav files on bootup with raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame, raspberry-pi3

I’m trying to have a wav file play from bootup on my raspberry pi 3 model B. I have tried pygame with no success and an os root but I still cannot get it to work. I have tested both my crontab and rc.local commands with a simple blinking led script and they both worked fine. However, when I substitute my audio player script it will work from the terminal, but not at startup. The code is...

```
from pygame import Button
import pygame
pygame.init()
song=pygame.mixer.Sound(‘/home/pi/test.wav1’)
button=Button(27)
while True:
   button.when_pressed=song.play(-1)
```

If anyone had just a sample piece or template I’m more than happy to change things around. I just can’t seem to figure out why it won’t work. I added a delay in crontab as well with no luck:(

Answer (score 0):

Essentially all you have to do to create a start-up script is the following:

Create a file here and make it executable:

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/start-sound && chmod +x $_
```

Add it to the default runlevel:

```
sudo update-rc.d start-sound defaults
```

All your script really needs to do is call aplay on an audio file. Something like this:

```
# /etc/init.d/start-sound

echo "Playing startup sound"
aplay /path/to/file.mp3 2>&1 >/dev/null &
```